# Reduction of nitrobenzen using LiAlH4

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stability

Can you please explain  why isn't nitrobenzene reduced to aniline but turns out as azobenzene on reaction with LiAlH4? Please explain the mechanism.

Comment: Duplicate: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88616/reduction-of-nitrobenzene-with-lialh4-and-nabh4?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 4):

It is entirely possible you form aniline, but it gets consumed. During the reduction nitrosobenzene would also be formed, and [Delmagro et al. [1]](https://doi.org/10.1002/poc.610070803) report that in basic solution the aniline can couple with the nitrosobenzene to give azobenzene. This coupling depends on the nitrogen in aniline acting as a nucleophile, so under acidic conditions as in a tin/hydrochloric acid reduction it would be suppressed (and thus aniline preserved/protected) by protonating the aniline. See also [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88616/reduction-of-nitrobenzene-with-lialh4-and-nabh4/88628#88628).

**Reference**

1.
Jacir Dalmagro, Rosendo A. Yunes, Edesio Luiz Simionatto. "Mechanism of reaction of azobenzene formation from aniline and nitrosobenzene in basic conditions. General base catalysis by hydroxyide ion". *Journal of Physical Organic Chemistry* **7** (8), 399-402. https://doi.org/10.1002/poc.610070803